# How can I count the rising edge of a square signals using python?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have a square signal using the following code. How can I count the rising edges using python?

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000, endpoint=True)
plt.plot(t, signal.square(2 * np.pi * 5 * t))
```

Following image represents my output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is super clean (like the signal provided), then just find the number of occurrences when the value is greater than the previous:

```
np.sum(np.diff(s) > 0) # 5
```

Comment: I guess `np.count_nonzero()` would work instead of `np.sum()`, and be more obvious? :)

Comment: well the given solution gives the number of the rising edge. Thats the solution. This worked with real data as well

Comment: note, this won't work well for noisy data.  A more robust solution would depend on the nature of the noise

Comment: @iamwhoiam: by curiosity, how do you get a signal so clean that this works ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I cant say that, props to our devs for sending clean data ;)

Comment: Maybe those who can send that data can tell the number of edges as well :-)